how To get rid of /public when deploy Laravel on shared host?
i have a Laravel project, and i have deployed it on Hostinger as a shared host,
my shared host structure :

[public_html] -> [contains all the files of laravel project also public of laravel]
[public_html] -> [contains .htaccess beside laravel project]


[.htaccess beside laravel project contains this] ->
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

the problem is
now everything working correctly but the problem is i have /public after my domain
it should be www.domain.com/
but i get    www.domain.com/public/
but also i can go to www.domain.com/login
also i can go to     www.domain.com/public/login
but i can not go to www.domain.com/
it redirects me back to www.domain.com/public/
how to solve it ? please

This question is similar to: Remove public from URL in Laravel 9 using .htaccess on shared hosting/CPanel hosting. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i just uploaded laravel beside

public_html

as laravel after that i went to laravel/public
and i moved all the files including htaccess of laravel project
to

public_html

after that i added the /laravel/ to each path in index.php
and this is everything , without doing anything further

The safest and simplest method is to use symlinks.
First, create a new directory outside public_html. I follow the practice of /home/username/domainname. For example, /home/arun/mysite.mydomain.com
Deploy and setup your Laravel application in this new directory. The index.php file and .htaccess file shipped by Laravel by default should be in the /home/username/domainname/public directory
Next delete your public_html directory
Now create a symlink from /home/username/domainname/public to /home/username/public_html
The command would be
ln -nfs /home/username/domainname/public /home/username/public_html

And that's it, your full application code will be in the domainname directory while only the contents of the  public directory will be in public_html
The main benefits of this approach is

Zero code changes
.env, vendor directory not accesible to the public increasing security
Easy to deploy, just deploy any changes to domainname directory and changes will automatically reflect


would this work on Hostinger ?

@momo I have not used Hostinger before, but it should work on any host that supports symlinks

does not work , i tried it.

@momo could you elaborate the issue? Does public still appear in the url, are you getting 404, or something else?

yes the public still appear to me.

Good day; for your website to work without /public

Put all your code outside public_html (name the folder anything)
Put only your public folder inside your public_html
Edit your domain to face public_html, I think this is currently set based on your explanation.
Edit index.php inside the public folder (e.g. public_html/public/index.php)
Set reference to bootstrap.php and autoload.php to reference your code folder outside of public_hmtl

An example is given below change (project_dir) to the directory you create the same level as public _html
require DIR.'/../(project_dir)/vendor/autoload.php'; // probably line 34
$app = require_once DIR.'/../(project_dir)/bootstrap/app.php'; //probably line 47
You might also need to set the permission for the public folder to 775 but this is not neccesary
